# Isomorphism between Hom and tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking for an explicit isomorphism $Hom(V,V^*)\rightarrow V^*\otimes V^*$ where $V$ is a vector space.

I thought of:

$\phi\rightarrow ((u,v)\rightarrow \phi(u)(v))$

But I'm not sure this works.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: What is your definition of $V\otimes V$, and how is the bilinear map$$(u,v)\mapsto \phi(u)(v)$$an element of it?

Comment: I see $V\otimes V$ as the space of all bilinear forms on $V\times V$

Comment: I think that is what most people would consider $(V\otimes V)^*$.

Comment: Isn't it the one also denoted $T^2(V)$?

Comment: For the map in the direction "Hom---> Tensor" you need to work with a basis on $V$. The other way round, as shown by @Andreas Caranti is easier and more natural.

Comment: I have edited the text accordingly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I normally think of it the other way around, that is,
$$
V^{\star} \otimes W \to \hom(V, W),
\qquad
\varphi \otimes w \mapsto (v \mapsto \varphi(v) w).
$$

---

**PS** I am assuming $V, W$ to be finite-dimensional, see the comments below.

Comment: How do you see that this map is surjective?

Comment: @Ian: Because vector space homomorphisms can be represented by matrices. The elementary matrix $E_{i,j}$ on a given bases $e,f$ of $V,W$, repspectively, is the image of $e_j^*\otimes f_i$. This even works in infinite dimension if you directly give a basis $e^*$ of $V^*$.

Comment: @Marc: is that approach also valid in infinite dimension?

Comment: I retract the part about infinite dimension. Indeed since tensor products contain only finite sums of elementary tensors, any homomorphism in the image of this correspondence has as image a finite dimensional subspace of $W$. Taking $V=W$ of infinite dimension, the identity of $V$ is not in the image of the correspondence.